# Spliting arrays at specific sizes

Tags: arrays, julia

Let's say i have an array with 10 elments:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Then I want to define a function that takes this arr as parameter to perform
a calculation, let's say for this example the calculation is the difference of means, for example:

**If N=2 (That means group the elements of arr in groups of size 2 sequentially):**

```
results=[]

result_1 = 1+2/2 - 3+4/2
result_2 = 3+4/2 - 5+6/2
result_3 = 5+6/2 - 7+8/2
result_4 = 7+8/2 - 9+10/2
```

The output would be:

```
results = [-2,-2,-2,-2]
```

**If N=3 (That means group the elements of arr in groups of size 3 sequentially):**

```
results=[]

result_1 = 1+2+3/3 - 4+5+6/3
result_2 = 4+5+6/3 - 7+8+9/3
```

The output would be:

```
results = [-3,-3]
```

I want to do this defining two functions:

**Function 1** - Creates the arrays that will be used as input for 2nd function:

```
 Parameters: array, N
 returns: k groups of arrays -> seems to be ((length(arr)/N) - 1)
```

**Function 2** - Will be the fucntion that gets the arrays (2 by 2) and perfoms the calculations, in this case, difference of means.

```
Parameters: array1,array2....arr..arr..
returns:  list of the results
```

**Important Note**

My idea is to apply these fucntions to a stream of data and the calculation will be the PSI (Population Stability Index)

So, if my stream has 10k samples and I set the first function to N=1000, then the output to the second function will be 1k samples + next 1k samples.

The process will be repetead till the end of the datastream

I was trying to do this in python (I already have the PSI code ready) but now I decided to use Julia for it, but I am pretty new to Julia.  So, if anyone can give me some light here will be very helpfull.

Comment: Not a `julia` programmer, I can Answer It but not in `julia`

Comment: I am looking for a solution in python also ;-)  I have the PSI code ready in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Julia if you have a big `Vector` and you want to calculate some statistics on groups of 3 elements you could do:

```
julia> a = collect(1:15);  #creates a Vector [1,2,...,15]

julia> mean.(eachcol(reshape(a,3,length(a)÷3)))
5-element Vector{Float64}:
  2.0
  5.0
  8.0
 11.0
 14.0
```

Note that both `reshape` and `eachcol` are non-allocating so no data gets copied in the process.
If the length of `a` is not divisible by `3` you could truncate it before reshaping - to avoid allocation use `view` for that:

```
julia> a = collect(1:16);

julia> mean.(eachcol(reshape(view(a,1:(length(a)÷3)*3),3,length(a)÷3)))
5-element Vector{Float64}:
  2.0
  5.0
  8.0
 11.0
 14.0
```

Depending on what you actually want to do you might also want to take a look at `OnlineStats.jl` https://github.com/joshday/OnlineStats.jl

Answer (score 1):

Well, I use JavaScript instead Of Python, But it would be same thing in python...

You need a `chunks` function, that take array and chunk_size (N), lets say `chunks([1,2,3,4], 2) -> [[1,2], [3,4]]`

we have a sum method that add all element in array, `sum([1,2]) -> 3`;

Both JavaScript and python support corouting, that you can use for lazy evaluation, And its called `Generator` function, this type of function can pause its execution, and can resume on demand! This is useful for calculate stream of data.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
// Javascript Doesn't support `chunks` method yet, So we need to create one...
Array.prototype.chunks = function* (N) {
    let chunk = [];
    for (let value of this) {
        chunk.push(value)
        if (chunk.length == N) {
            yield chunk;
            chunk = []
        }
    }
}
Array.prototype.sum = function () {
    return this.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
}
function* fnName(arr, N) {
    let chunks = arr.chunks(N);
    let a = chunks.next().value.sum();
    for (let b of chunks) {
        yield (a / N) - ((a = b.sum()) / N)
    }
}
console.log([...fnName(arr, 2)])
console.log([...fnName(arr, 3)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I'll look for keywords you said: chunks, coroutines, lazy evaluation.  This is exactly what I am looking for xD